# Dynamic imports + relative imports in Python 3

Tags: python, import, python-3.x

I have a **Python 3** project where I'm dynamically importing modules from disk, using `imp.load_module`. But, I've run into an problem where relative imports fail, when the relative import occurs within a dynamically imported module.

From what I've read, I came to the conclusion that only `__file__`, `__path__`, `__package__`, and `__name__` were used by the default importer when determining the path of an import. Yet, I've verified these in the code below, and it still fails when dynamically imported. (It works when imported in the interpreter with an updated `sys.path`)

```
# File structure:
# [root]
#  ├─ __init__.py
#  ├─ board.py
#  └─ test.py
```

```
# Contents of 'board.py':
import os, sys
import root  # Already imported... just need a reference

ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(root.__file__)
assert root is sys.modules['root']
assert root.__package__ is None
assert root.__name__ == 'root'
assert root.__file__ == os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, '__init__.py')
assert not hasattr(root, '__path__')

xx = object()
assert xx is sys.modules['root.board'].xx
assert __package__ is None
assert __name__ == 'root.board'
assert __file__ == os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'board.py')
assert not hasattr(sys.modules['root.board'], '__path__')

assert os.path.isfile(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'test.py'))
from . import test  # ImportError('cannot import name test',)
```

But if I hack `sys.path` and reimport the current package just before the failed import, it works:

```
oldroot = root
del sys.modules['root']
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(ROOT_DIR))
import root
from . import test  # No error here
```

And further, the four golden attributes mentioned above are the same in both the new and old packages:

```
assert oldroot.__package__ == root.__package__
assert oldroot.__name__ == root.__name__
assert oldroot.__file__ == root.__file__
assert not hasattr(root, '__path__')
```

Which means that `__package__`, `__name__`, `__file__`, and `__path__` can't be the full story. Are there any other attributes that Python uses to locate imports? What am I overlooking that would cause the import to fail?

Comment: Can you give more information on your reproduction step? How are you loading your module?

Comment: The paths are user-specified, but here are the two logged dynamic import calls: `imp.load_module('root', <_io.TextIOWrapper>, '<project-dir>\\root\\__init__.py', ('.py', 'r', 1))` and `imp.load_module('root.board', <_io.TextIOWrapper>, '<project-dir>\\root\\board.py', ('.py', 'r', 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of a `root.__path__` value is suspicious (it means Python doesn't consider `root` to be a package).

The fact that both `load_module()` calls are being made with a type value of `1` (a module) instead of the first one having a type of `5` (a package) is also highly dubious.

Are you using `imp.find_module()` to work out the correct inputs to the `imp.load_module()` call?

For a package, the input to `imp.load_module()` should look something like this:

```
# demo is a package in the current directory for this example
>>> info = imp.find_module('demo')
>>> info
(None, 'demo', ('', '', 5))
>>> demo = imp.load_module('demo', *info)
>>> demo.__path__
['demo']
```

Comment: I'm not using `load_module`, I'm figuring out everything by hand. But this answer sounds very promising... I wasn't even aware of type `5`, since it isn't listed in `imp.get_suffixes()`. I'm trying this now.

Comment: Well, that was deceptively simple, but it worked. Thanks a million!

Comment: Yeah, the suffixes table only covers Python source and bytecompiled files. C extensions, builtin modules, package directories, frozen modules and the like have their own type flags. `load_module` is really designed to be used in conjunction with `find_module` though - `PEP 302` has all the gory details.