# Import parent directory for brief tests

Tags: python-3.x, pythonpath, project-layout

I have searched this site top to bottom yet have not found a single way to actually accomplish what I want in Python3x. This is a simple toy app so I figured I could write some simple test cases in asserts and call it a day. It does generate reports and such so I would like to make sure my code doesn't do anything wonky upon changes.

My current directory structure is: (only relevant parts included)

```
project
  -model
     __init__.py
     my_file.py
     -test
       my_file_test.py
```

I am having a hell of a time getting my_file_test.py to import my_file.py.

Like I've said. I've searched this site top to bottom and no solution has worked. My version of Python is 3.2.3 running on Fedora 17.

Previously tried attempts:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078590/dynamic-imports-relative-imports-in-python-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655526/how-to-accomplish-this-relative-import-in-python)
[Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/python-importing-modules-from-parent-folder)
[Can anyone explain python's relative imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918539/can-anyone-explain-pythons-relative-imports)
[How to accomplish relative import in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655526/how-to-accomplish-this-relative-import-in-python)

In virtually every attempt I get an error to the effect of:

ImportError: No module named * 
OR
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

What is going on here. I have tried every accepted answer on SO as well as all over the interwebs. Not doing anything that fancy here but as a .NET/Java/Ruby programmer this is proving to be the absolute definition of intuitiveness.

EDIT: If it matters I tried loading the class that I am trying to import in the REPL and I get the following:

```
>>> import datafileclass
>>> datafileclass.methods
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>>> x = datafileclass('sample_data/sample_input.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

If it matters...I know the functionality in the class works but I can't import it which in the now is causing an inability to test. In the future will certainly cause integration issues. (names changed to protect the innocent)
getting within a couple of weeks of desired functionality for this iteration of the library...any help could be useful. Would have done it in Ruby but the client wants the Python as a learning experience,

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Structure your code like this:

```
project
  -model
    __init__.py
    my_file.py
  -tests
    __init__.py
    test_my_file.py
```

Importantly, your `tests` directory should also be a module directory (have an empty `__init__.py` file in it).

Then in test_my_file.py use `from model import my_file`, and from the top directory run `python -m tests.test_my_file`.  This is invoking `test_my_file` as a module, which results in Python setting up its import path to include your top level.

Even better, you can use pytest or nose, and running `py.test` will pick up the tests automatically.

I realise this doesn't answer your question, but it's going to be a lot easier for you to work with Python standard practices rather than against them.  That means structuring your project with tests in their own top-level directory.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try this evening. That was similar to my original structure but I stumbled across some resource that stated I should structure it this way. I'll let you know how it works out once I'm out of work.

Comment: This causes an "ImportError: No module named model" error at line 1 (the import statement). What is up with this picture.

Comment: Is there some sort of explicit annotations I need in my class to make it importable? Not really versed in python and its been a while since I've even used it (which was only in a teaching capacity then).

Comment: ...should I have content in the __init__.py? Nothing seems to indicate it should have anything

Comment: @Rig no, `__init__.py` is allowed to be empty.  I forgot to specify that `tests` should also have an `__init__.py` and to invoke the tests using `-m` syntax.

Comment: No go. python3 -m test.PaypalCSVPayDataFileTest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.2/runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.2/runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/media/sf_My_Projects/washmypy/test/PaypalCSVPayDataFileTest.py", line 8, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/sf_My_Projects/washmypy/test/PaypalCSVPayDataFileTest.py", line 4, in main
    file1 = PaypalCSVPayDataFile('/sample_data/sample_paypal_input.csv')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: EDIT: I stand corrected. You were correct and I found a non related problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this - it solved my problem. But what effect does ensuring __init__.py exists in the test directory actually *have*? Why does it solve the problem?

Comment: @Zxaos providing `__init__.py` turns the directory into a module, allowing it to be imported.

Comment: @ecatmur right, but I'm not importing the tests module. Why does making the test directory into a module fix the import of the external module that I'm testing?